# When serving Angular.js 1.3.4 through mean.js cannot access variables or controllers within curly braces

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

When serving Angular 1.3 from Mean.js angular seems to evaluate simple curly brace expressions but they cannot access variables within the current scope. For example in the following code the simple sum evaluates correctly, the `ng-bind` evaluates correctly, but the curly brace expression which tries to access a variable does not

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app ng-init="firstName = 'John'; lastName = 'Doe';">
  <strong>Simple sum:</strong> 2+2={{2+2}}<br />
  <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
  <strong>Last name:</strong> <span ng-bind="lastName"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

This results in:

> Simple sum: 2+2=4
>
> First name:
>
> Last name: Doe

That is `{{2+2}}` is evaluated but `{{firstName}}` is not

Similarly while I can access controllers within directives I cannot seem to access controllers from within curly brackets expressions. i.e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personController">

    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName +" "+ lastName}}
    

  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

  app.controller('personController', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.firstName = "David";
   $scope.lastName = "Silva";
 })
</script>

</html>
```

Results in

> First Name: David
>
> Last Name:  Silva
>
> Full Name:

That is `{{firstName +" "+ lastName}}` is not evaluated even though  within the same scope is bound to the correct variable

EDIT

This problem cannot be replicated using jsfiddle and is to do with the server (Mean.js). I confirmed this by serving the exact same html page & JS files though playframework with no problems. So the question is now "*what is mean.js doing which breaks angular in the above way*"

Comment: create a plunker or fiddle of it i didn't find anything wrong in your code .

Comment: Seems to work in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6XpoUegBfydM3HaCqoys?p=preview Serving it though MEAN.js so could be something to do with a minifier or something.

Comment: So, Is there any error in console in your own program ?

Comment: No no errors in console

Comment: So there must be problem somewhere else in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code, using the same version of angular, and could not reproduce the issue you are having.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

  app.controller('personController', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.firstName = "David";
   $scope.lastName = "Silva";
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personController">

    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName +" "+ lastName}}


</div>
```

On a side note, not directly related, you should migrate to the controllerAs syntax. This will help you in always have an object.property in your expressions and bindings. This will allow JavaScript references to work as expected, which may be causing issues similar to what you are reporting.

Your example will then look like:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('PersonController', PersonController);

PersonController.$inject = ['$http'];
function PersonController($http) {
   this.firstName = "David";
   this.lastName = "Silva";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PersonController as vm">

    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{vm.firstName +" "+ vm.lastName}}


</div>
```